# Community Wiki Reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, community-wiki

One of my answers was downvoted to -3 (no big deal, it's for the Tim Post contest) and I lost -6 reputation (again, the rep isn't a big deal at all). When my answer was turned into a community wiki,I noticed that the reputation persisted.

Is this supposed to be like that?

Maybe instead, if a question/answer is Community Wiki'd, revert all reputation gained/lost from the post?

Comment: In the event of a contest, your request seems reasonable at first glance. However, think of all the *other* reasons a post goes CW, though. There's no reason someone with a great answer should lose his initial rep if it gets edited over time by others.

Comment: If my primary-school prealgebra class taught me anything, it's that "losing -6 reputation" is a good thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is by design.  Rep changes from before a post is CW-ed remain, rep changes *after* the conversion don't affect rep.

If this weren't the case people could just CW any answer that gets a lot of downvotes as a way of invalidating all of those votes.

Additionally, the entire concept behind CW is that the post is not "owned" by one person, but rather many.  Because many people own it, and have contributed to it, it wouldn't make sense for only the author's rep to be affected by votes.  Rather than complicate the system through an intricate system of "sharing" the rep changes, it's easier just to remove it entirely.  Votes before a post is made CW were votes on content authored by just one person; there aren't other contributors to complicate matters.

Comment: Ok, is there a given reason why?

Comment: Yes I understand the CW concept, but if your post is turned into a CW, what's the reasoning to not revert usergained reputation? (Can it be turned into a CW without your permission?)

Comment: @RUJordan I have given two reasons in my answer, I'm sure others exist.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @RUJordan - One example, other than what Servy explained here, that I encountered: I had been maintaining an answer as circumstances changed. Eventually after a year it hit the edit limit and was converted into a CW with +16 votes on it. Reverting the rep from that seems like it would be counter productive.