# Community Wiki Question

Tags: support, community-wiki

Why was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596647/ignore-br-with-css/18040142#18040142) answer turned community wiki? Only two users have revised it. I  saw [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212949/community-wiki-reputation) that the idea behind CW is that the OP is not the sole owner of the post but many users own it. Is there a lower limit on the number of users editing the post which if crossed then the question turns CW?

Comment: That's not a question. It is an answer. With 14 revisions.

Comment: it has been revised 14 times...

Answer (score 2):

It was edited at least 10 times by you.

It says so in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18040142/revisions):

> added 45 characters in body; [made Community Wiki by Aneesh Karthik C editing at least 10 times]

From the [Community Wiki FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts):

> Posts enter community wiki mode when one of the following happens:
>
> [...]
>
> - The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner.

This is a rate limiting measure, see [Why does repeated editing by same user lead to community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179901/why-does-repeated-editing-by-same-user-lead-to-community-wiki/179902#179902)

From that answer:

> If this bites you for legitimate reasons (your answer evolved over time, following the complexities of a changing question, or because of new insights to a complex problem), flag your post for moderator attention, use other and request that a moderator revert the CW flag change.